# Unable to use FirebaseUI pod on a new project - AppAuth.framework not found

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup a new Xcode project with cocoapod FirebaseUI. When I compile and run the project, I get this error:

```
Frameworks/AppAuth.framework: No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had a ' in the App name.